# Server with different clients in Qt

Tags: qt

I need to create an application that:

- Has one server
- With a client that connects to the server and sends 8 longs (data from 8 sensors: rain, air humidity, wind speed...) 1 sensor data / long (sensor data is acquired from a custom USB device)
- User clients. The end user runs this type of client to connect to the server for data retrieval from the sensors.

I used Qt before, creating Client-server applications with just one type of client. And I managed to create this application too, just at a smaller scale (used 5 words, and clients were connected simultaneously to the server). I used the Qt network examples fortune threaded server and  http://goo.gl/srypT and blocking fortune client example.

How can i identify which client is which? (since they have different ip everytime they connect to internet). On my small scale application, I created some kind of protocol, but there must be a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to identify the client **type** ("sensor client" vs. "user client"), not individual client instances.

The straightforward way to do this is to implement a protocol, as mentioned in the question. For your use case, this could be very simple:

- let the "sensor client" send a "write" command (one character like "w" would be sufficient) followed by your sensor data. The server then receives the "w" command and knows that he needs to read sensor data from the client.
- let the "user client" send a "read" command (e.g. the character "r"). When the server receives the "r" command it knows that it needs to send data to the client.

If, for whatever reason, you do not want to implement even such a simple protocol, you could also set up two separate QTcpServer instances which listen at different ports, lets say 8192 and 8193. Your "sensor client" would then connect to port 8192, and the server knows by the port number that the client will send data. Your "user clients" would connect to port 8193, and the server knows that the clients expect data and will send the required data.

In any case, you should be aware that there is no authentication and authorization involved, and any client who knows the simple protocol and/or the port numbers can send and receive data.

Comment: I've implemented the solution with two separate QTcpServer instances and it works really nice. Now i need to make some kind of authentication... but this is another issue. Thanks for the great answers, it really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

To identify a client, you have to use some kind of client ID. Usually, some kind of hash (a MD5 digest, a UUID or a GUID) is used as the client ID. This client ID have to be sent from the client to the server when the client connects to the server.

What happens after the client has been identified and accepted, depends on the type of connection (protocol). If you use a stateful protocol, the same connection will be kept open as long as the client uses it so there is no need to re-identify the client. If you use a stateless connection (HTTP, for example), you will have to re-send the same ID from the client to the server every time the client requires data (that is: a document, a page, etc.) to the server.

A simpler and more efficent way to deal with a client/server architecture like this consists in using an existing, proven server of some kind. For example, you could use a RESTful web server like Wt (http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/blog), given that you are already using C++.

Even better, I would use a Ruby- or a Python-based RESTful web service framework like:

http://www.sinatrarb.com/

http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/

http://flask.pocoo.org/

Or the new Ruby-on-Rails API:

http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2012-11-22-introducing-the-rails-api-project

https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api

Developing the server in Ruby or Python is much faster and easier. The client can developed in any way (C++ with Qt, Javascript in a web browser and many other ways)